# ESAPI Logger throwing org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: SecurityConfiguration for HttpUtilities.MaxHeaderNameSize has incorrect type

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, esapi

Using the below code in my application for generating an excel file as a attachment to the API Response header.

App Code:

```
ESAPI.httpUtilities().setHeader(response,"Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + "");
```

After changing to  ESAPI 2.2.3.1 and excluding log4J due to the vulnerability issues and added the below lines in ESAPI.Properties
`ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.logging.slf4j.Slf4JLogFactory Logger.UserInfo=false Logger.ClientInfo=false`
i'm getting below error in my app. I have the same ESAPI.properties with ESAPI version 2.0.1 which is working fine for the above app code.
Error Message:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: SecurityConfiguration for HttpUtilities.MaxHeaderNameSize has incorrect type] with root cause
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: SecurityConfiguration for HttpUtilities.MaxHeaderNameSize has incorrect type
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultSecurityConfiguration.getIntProp(DefaultSecurityConfiguration.java:1265)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities.setHeader(DefaultHTTPUtilities.java:890)
    at com.caremore.togetherness.controller.ExportDataController.getMemberReferralData(ExportDataController.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have missed a property in your esapi.properties file in your project which is required in the latest dependency of org.owasp.esapi 2.2.3.1 library/jar
Once you update the esapi.properties file to include the missing entry

```
HttpUtilities.MaxHeaderNameSize=256
```

Which I have noticed in [this link](https://github.com/VascoArreaza/OwaspJava/blob/master/esapi-java-legacy-develop/configuration/esapi/ESAPI.properties).
It might workout as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PmsT.png)  which has the difference between the files

Comment: Please don't show text as code but prefer copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

When updating ESAPI, check history here for new properties and other changes you will have to/might want to apply as well:
https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/commits/develop/configuration/esapi/ESAPI.properties
That one includes Logger.UserInfo and Logger.ClientInfo.